# RequestDispatcher.forward() to resource under “/WebContent” doesn't work

Tags: java

I am dispatching a request to html resource in Webcontent folder in servlet. But its not dispatching it. Even its not giving any exception. AboutUs is an html page placed in **WebContent** folder of project. The IDE i am using is eclipse. I am very new to web development. any help will be appreciated.

*Thanks in advance.*

Servlet Code:

```
@WebServlet("/Login")
public class Login extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Login() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String name="";
        String pass="";
        name=request.getParameter("param1");
        pass=request.getParameter("param2");
        System.out.println("Name :" +name+"PAss :"+pass);
        if (name!=null && pass!=null){
        List<User> please = DataAccessUtil.getByEmail(name, pass);
        if (please!=null)
        {
            int count  = please.size();
            System.out.println("Record Found : " + count);
            if(!(count==0))
            {
                Iterator<User> iterator = please.iterator();
                while(iterator.hasNext())
                {

                    User object = (User) iterator.next();
                    String email = object.getEmail();
                    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
                    session.setMaxInactiveInterval(60);
                    session.setAttribute("email", email);

                }
                RequestDispatcher r= request.getRequestDispatcher("/AboutUs.html");
                r.forward(request, response);


                log("please");
            }
            else{
                RequestDispatcher rd= request.getRequestDispatcher("/DR.html");
                rd.forward(request, response);
                log("please2");
            }
        }
        }
        else{

        }
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

Comment: be much more specific what is the error ?

Comment: Thats the problem there is no explicit error being reported by eclipse during execution. But this line of code is not working. Its not opening that page despite of the fact that very next line that is simply Log("clicked") is executing.

Comment: show us all the servlet code here

Comment: actually the sequence of execution is that from index.html request is sent to my Login servlet which authenticates and dispatches request to  AboutUs.html. But AboutUs.html never gets open in browser.

Comment: show the doget(){} code in Login servlet

Comment: try that HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect("/AboutUs.html"); for an instant instead of RequestDispatcher r= request.getRequestDispatcher("/AboutUs.html");
                r.forward(request, response);
  and see if it works

Comment: another thing does the log("please") pass ?

Comment: No its not working. Its giving me exception: Exception in thread "http-bio-8080-exec-51" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

Comment: but look up at the url bar has it changed ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing to get OutOfMemoryError but one thing you're obviously doing wrong: in `while(iterator.hasNext())` you keep overriding the same `session.setAttribute("email", email);` attribute

Comment: response.sendRedirect("/AboutUs.html"); i wrote this line, error has been removed but still no url change , no progress.. :(

Comment: have you tried to write it in that way instead request.getRequestDispatcher("AboutUs.html");

Comment: No thats working perfectly fine because it do authenticate from database that the user is valid or not. (that has been checked separately)

Comment: yup i have written. Its also giving the same effect. (no error but not opening that page too.. )

Comment: request.requestDispatcher("AboutUs.html").forward(request, response); try it all in one line and remove the 2 others

Comment: i have tried it already. no use.

Comment: another thing is that if i write the url of servlet in browser directly instead of coming through index.html , it works fine. dispatch statement does get executed. Does this help you to get an answer?